# pygame.display.get_surface() as default param in func equals None, but in a func the command returns value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

When I put pygame.display.get_surface() as default param in func it gives me None, example:

```
def func(surface = pygame.display.get_surface()):
    print(surface)
```

And I get None.

But if I do this:

```
def func():
    print(pygame.display.get_surface())
```

It will print me the details of it (for example: Surface(800x600x32 SW))

What is the reason for it to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(surface=pygame.display.get_surface()):
    print(surface)
```

This calls `pygame.display.get_surface()` when the function is **defined**, not when it is called.

When the function itself is being created, you didn't initialize the pygame yet, so `pygame.display.get_surface()` returns `None`.

The alternative, as you noticed, is to move the `get_surface()` call from the definition of the function to the body:

```
def func(surface=None):
    if surface is None:
         surface = pygame.display.get_surface()
    print(surface)
```